# React Native Some Video Thumbnails are Black

Tags: react-native

I am implementing a custom video picker on my app to get videos from users gallery. I found out that if i pass video uri to image component it automatically shows thumbnail for that video.

```
<Image
    ...
    source={{ uri: this.props.video.uri }}
/>
```

It is working for 95 percent of videos but some videos -especially ones that i downloaded from internet- just have black thumbnails. Is there a way to prevent this behavior or how can i detect black thumbnails so i can use external library to get thumbnail for that video.

Thanks.